# Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' on logging out from Asp.Net Identity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using Asp.Net identity for authentication purpose.While I am logging out from the application it shows following error

[image]

[image]

[image]

dependencies bundle is my angularjs bundle which consist of many other modules.
Using _LoginPartial page for showing login , signup and user dropdown.

```
   @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

_LoginPartial View

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" , @style="display:inline" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="pc-name-button">
            <a href="" class="pc-header-login-button pc-name-link" header-dropdown-link>
                <span class="pc-name">@User.Identity.GetUserName()</span>
                <span class="i-icon i-glyph-icon-30-downcarrot"></span>
            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu i-linklist-dropdown pc-header-accountDropdown">
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Admin Panel", "Index", "Admin")

                }
                else
                {
                    <a href="#">My Fundraisers</a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.personal.my_donations">My Donations</span></a>
                    <a href="#">My Settings</a>
                }
                <a href="javascript: document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"  delete-link>Log Out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Login","Account")" class="pc-header-login-button">
        Log In
     </a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Register","Account")" style="margin-left:7px;" class="pc-header-login-button">
        Sign Up
    </a>
}
```

Here is the controller action

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

What I am doing wrong Need help ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did myself.By making an angular module and controller that submits the logout form.
Here is the code

```
(function () {

angular.module('LogOffModule', []).
controller('LogOffController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function () {
        $('#logoutForm').submit();

    };
}]);
```

})();